# Building QtWebKit with QT 5.6 on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qt5.6

I'm trying to compile QtWebkit with VS2015, QT 5.6 itself builds fine. Since webkit module was removed  in 5.6 I reverted revision
`SHA-1: 4116ec2474e608c9a752ace5e8eb92cbd4052ebc "* Removed QtWebkit and QtWebkit-Examples from qt5.git"` so I can get webkit module downloaded when I run "init-repository". However while building, I'm getting a linker error which does not make any sense:

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\bin\jsc.exe @C:\Users\PAVLOD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nmA33.tmp

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '\OPT:REF.obj'
```

I had no problem building QtWebkit with QT 5.5.1. Something has changed in 5.6 which prevents it being built out of the box. Most likely I've got my dependencies wrong. How would I even begin debugging a problem? I tried running that command manually, but it complained that it couldn't find .tmp file. I assume that build scripts generate temp files for something then deletes them.
The file it tried to link *I think* is related to jsc.cpp, because it's what it tried to compile right before linking.

Comment: Not really an answer, but shouldn't you try to port your code to the new QtWebEngine framework? If that is not possible I'd downgrade your qt version to a version that supported the QtWebkit. It seems to me that if you would continuously run into issues if you try to use a module in a Qt version that no longer supports it, even if you somehow manage to get it to work

Comment: Thanks, WebEngine is considerably bulkier, slower, runs out of process and takes more memory than WebKit. The app also relies on some WebKit functionality, but it's less of my worries.
Also the app has to use 5.6, because of its better High DPI support.

Comment: I found `\OPT:REF` in `qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/Makefile.jsc.Release:20`.

`LIBS          = ... \OPT:REF ...`

Right option is `/OPT:REF`, not `\OPT:REF`

Comment: FYI https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50607

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce and got the same error, but in my case linker call look like

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\bin\jsc.exe @D:\Temp\_system\nmB77B.tmp
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '\OPT:REF.obj'
```

Here we have /OPT:REF linker argument that is somehow treatened as an input file. You can try to change this parameter in build configuration and see what happens. Good luck)